# Canon LBP and HP Laserjet 1020 say "Document Printed" but nothing prints

Tags: printing, canon, hplip

My printer is being recognized, installed.

When I am trying to print anything it's saying

"Document Printed"

and

"Documnt has been sent for printing"

but nothing is actually printed.

I've tried CANON LBP printers and HP LaserJet 1020

Comment: have you checked to make sure your printer is set as the default? It may be printing to some other device...

Comment: @Rory Alsop, sure I checked.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have printer drivers installed?

My laserjet worked initially on ubuntu 11.10 but stopped working after an update. Then I started getting exactly the same kind of error you described and tried a few things before I got it working.

Try these commands.

```
hp-setup
```

This will help find and install the printer.

Then I used

```
system-config-printer
```

I found multiple installations for HP-Laserjet-1020 on my system.. tried printing test pages from all. I kept the printer profile that worked as default and deleted others.

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure your printer via CUPS http://localhost:631/